# Browser action opening context menu in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am currently working on a Chrome Extension, and facing a small issue. I want to use an icon for the extension, so I added this sample code to my manifest:

```
"icons": {
    "16": "images/logo.png",
    "48": "images/logo.png",
    "128": "images/logo.png"
},
```

However, the icon colors didn't appear, so I looked on the internet, and saw that I need to add a browser action in order to get a beautiful icon with colors, so I added this code to my manifest:

```
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/logo.png"
}
```

Here is the issue: **now the context menu is only accessible when I right click on the icon...**

Is there a way to open the context menu when I left click on the icon, and keep the colors on my icon?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd love to have that as well. Sometimes I'm too lazy to develop a custom popup and that would make for a nice way to show a quick UI to the user. I've tried various ways but unfortunately there currently seems to be no way to show the native contextMenu on left-click on the badgeIcon. :-/

Answer (score 0):

In **Chromium** you may execute `chrome.browserAction.disable()`, the icon will become grayscale but context menu will be accessible via both left and right clicks.

If FireFox menu is still not shown on left click.